# Logo Quiz app rejected by App Store three times!

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I made a Logo Quiz app for my country, and of course it includes protected third-party logos in app icon and screenshots, just like hundreds of other Logo Quiz apps already out on the App Store. Version 1.0 and 1.1 got approved and is out on the App Store, but I want to get version 1.3 out, but it keeps getting rejected.

The reason they give me is this: `Your app includes protected third-party logos in the app icon, screenshots, or previews.`

And it has now gotten rejected three times! Does anyone have a clue what to do to get it approved? Does same Apple-reviewer review my app? Could it work to delete the app, and create a new one to get a new reviewer?

Comment: "app icon, screenshots, or previews" - maybe the problem is an icon?

Comment: Keep in mind - we never try to answer why did Apple do X - those get closed as off topic. I've chosen to try and point at the guidelines, but we are probably the wrong site for anything more nuanced than - "I don't know where the app review guidelines are documented - can you point me to them, please?"

Comment: This also looks like a duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115605/app-was-rejected-for-use-of-protected-3rd-party-material  and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177192/ - I will include them in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I would probably rip out all the logos and see if your app is viable without the copyright issues involved with third party logos - especially ones in your marketing material.

Barring that, let's assume you can and do get clearance to use the logos of the companies and then resubmit, I'm thinking you're going to have a long road to approval even if you get past using / selling / profiting by / advertising against other people's logos.

If you look at the summary guidelines, your next likely risks of being rejected summarily for "hundreds of other apps" in the same category.

- https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/rejections/

Also the "lasting value" qualifier would likely be a hurdle for you to pass - especially if your app functionality could be easily done as a web app (take or leave that last one if it applies to you - I have no way to know if your logo quiz uses unique iOS API but the broad category seems better done as web apps).

There is also discussion on these two posts about "but officer, other people were speeding" and how to appeal a metadata rejection:

- [App was rejected for use of protected 3rd party material](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115605/)
- [How to react on Appstore rejection of screenshots?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177192/)